# Resize as a function of distance between mc's

Tags: actionscript-3

I hope this hasn't been asked too much before. When I search I only get questions pertaining to rescaling to window size.

Now my question. I got one space ship firing a beam against another ship. I want the beam to show for some time and I want it to "bridge" the two ships. In other words, I want the beam to extend its width between the two ships.

I try to do this with a dot movie clip that is 1 pixel wide and high (and aligned left edge). I try to resize it with the following code: (target is the ship to be fire at and owner is the ship firing)

```
dist.vx = target.x - owner.x;
dist.vy = target.y - owner.y;
dist.dist = Math.sqrt(dist.vx*dist.vx + dist.vy*dist.vy);

width = dist.dist;

x = owner.x;
y = owner.y;
rotation = Math.atan2(target.y-y, target.x-x)*180/Math.PI;
```

This doesn't work as intended because 1) dot also gets alot bigger in the other dimension - how can I "turn off" this behavior? and 2) sometimes it seems to get way to wide - but only in certain angles...

Any suggestions on either solving the heigh/width scaling or on another way to achieve the same effect?

(I'm new to coding and flash.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By resizing a dot, you will have a rectangle...

You can dynamically create a sprite covering both ships and **moveTo** the hit point of one ship then **lineTo** the other ship... You do not need distance calculation at all. What you have to do is being careful on the placement of the sprite. So that you can calculate relative hitting points by simple math.

Suppose you have mc **space** contining mc **ship1** and mc **ship2**, and hit point coords on ships are named **hx**, **hy** and you will use sprite **s**, calculation will be as follows.

```
// calculate hit points relative to mc space
var s1HX:int = ship1.x + ship1.hx, 
    s1HY:int = ship1.y + ship1.hy,
    s2HX:int = ship2.x + ship2.hx,
    s2HY:int = ship2.y + ship2.hy,
// sprite relative moveTo lineTo coords will be these.
    mX: int, mY: int,
    lX: int, lY: int;

// top left of sprite will be minimum of the hit coords.   
s.x = (s1HX <= s2HX)? s1HX : s2HX;
s.y = (s1HY <= s2HY)? s1HY : s2HY;

// now we can get sprite relative moveTo lineTo coordinates:
mX = s1HX - s.x;  
mY = s1HY - s.y;
lX = s2HX - s.x;
lY = s2HY - s.y;
```

The rest is implementation with using these with fancy line styles etc...

To create a new sprite:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

Adding / removing it to/from mc space:

```
space.addChild(s); 
space.removeChild(s);
```

For graphics use the graphics object of sprite.

```
s.graphics
```

For setting line styles you can use:

```
s.graphics.lineStyle(...) , 
s.graphics.lineBitmapStyle(...),
s.graphics.lineGradientStyle(...)
```

Functions, please read the manual for usage.

After setting the line style to draw the line use:

```
s.graphics.moveTo(mX,mY);
s.graphics.lineTo(lX,lY);
```

For pulsating effects you have to do a little more complicated things such as using tween class which you can read about here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

Note that:
Sprites are no complicated magic, they are like mc's but they do not have timelines etc.

Sprites try to scale when width or height change programmatically. So do not touch them, moveTo lineTo automatically sets the size of a sprite...

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I'm new to flash I don't understand your answer. Thanks tough! What is hx? x relative to the "mother mc"? I can't access any property called mc.hx. And when I try it out, I try it with sp.graphics.moveTo(mx, my) and sp.graphics(lx, lx) but it doesn't seem to work. Would it possible for you to add in some of the surrounding code? I've never worked it sprites. Also I want the beam to pulsate/animate - would that be possible through your way? Hope it's my ignorance and not disrespect that comes across. Thanks again

Comment: I mean that when I try it out I skip the +hx. My mc are on the same coordinate system anyway, but probably I missunderstand something

Comment: hx and hy is an x,y coordinate of a fictional point on a ship. So they are relative to the ship origin. I thought that you will want to hit the ships from same point on them, not always the origin. And I do not know how you set the ship and space origin of coordinate system. I prefer them to be at the top left, some people prefer center. Since I do not know how you organize your code and classes it is hard for me to extrapolate an example to fit into it. But I will add hints to my answer.